# Wrap XML Output on ASP.NET Web API

Tags: xml-parsing, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, roku

So I'm working on a web API that a Roku Channel will interact with to send and receive data. Roku SDK has a built in XML Parser that is easy to use, but the only problem is that Roku will only parse XML wrapped in an `<rsp stat="ok"></rsp>` element. I don't see how or where to override the XML Output on the web API to wrap it with the `<rsp>` element.

So my question is, how can I override the XML Formatter and insert `<rsp stat="ok">` before the output, and `</rsp>` after?

Comment: Hii, you know about, how much maximum time Required for response handle in Roku Side?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ensuring that you will return only XML by removing JSON formatter like this

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

you can use a message handler to add the envelope blindly for all responses like this.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                       HttpRequestMessage request,
                                            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        string responseBody = "<rsp stat=\"ok\">" + 
                                  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() +
                              "</rsp>";
        response.Content = new StringContent(
                          responseBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
        return response;
    }
}
```